# Duplicating an ssh private key file

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a private key under `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Running `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` confirms that the key is valid.

I'm trying to create another file containing this key. For example,

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa.dupe
chmod 0400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa (to make permissions the same for both files)
```

But when I run `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.dupe`, I get `~/.ssh/id_rsa.dupe is not a key file.`

Comment: [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com) are better choices for questions that aren't about *writing code*.

Comment: That said -- when you read or md5sum the files, does that confirm that they're identical?

Comment: Noted -- thank you @CharlesDuffy. And yes, running md5sum returns the same hash value for each file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. `ssh-keygen -l` refers to a *public key file*, per its documentation:

> ```
>   -l     Show fingerprint of specified public key file.
> ```

If you want to generate a private key and generate a public key, you can use `-y` to do that:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.dupe >~/.ssh/id_rsa.dupe.pub
ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.dupe.pub
```